# Warnings when building backend Express/WS Node app with Webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I am getting some confusing warnings when building a backend Node server with Webpack.  I want to use Webpack to build my backend primarily for two reasons:

- Webpack creates a single executable file, which is easier to deploy
- Webpack includes all of my app's dependencies, so I can deploy my app to any compatible Node environment without needing to install dependencies first

Here are the warnings I'm getting:

```
WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in .../node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 35:21-42
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Receiver.js
 @ ./~/ws/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js

WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in .../node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:22-47
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Receiver.js
 @ ./~/ws/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js

WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
80:29-41 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

For the `Critical dependency` warning, I've found a [good example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.context#examplejs) explaining the problem and some documentation on how to use the [ContextReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/), although it's still unclear to me how to apply it to this situation.  It looks like the warning is being caused by line 80 in `node_modules/express/lib/view.js`:

```
opts.engines[this.ext] = require(mod).__express
```

It is clear to me that the dependency cannot be resolved at build time, so how can I use the ContextReplacementPlugin to fix this dependency?

As for the `Module not found` warnings in the `ws` package, it's unclear to me what's going on.  It looks like those dependencies exist in my *global* `node_modules`, and maybe they're not being pulled in by Webpack.  I've tried adding them to my project's devDependencies, but then I just get `Critical dependency` warnings for them instead.

My application still runs after being built, so I suppose I could technically ignore the warnings, but I figure that these are widely used Node packages and Webpack is a popular build tool, so there must be a reasonable solution available.

---

Here are my dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cassandra-driver": "^0.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/uuid": "^2.0.29",
    "@types/ws": "0.0.40",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cassandra-driver": "^3.2.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "ws": "^2.3.1"
  }
```

And here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  }
};
```

I like keeping things minimal if possible.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Since Webpack is meant to build browser applications, you'll need to tweak a bit your configuration in order to bypass some of the webpack default behaviours. This is a good read to get started: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I

Comment: @toomuchdesign Thanks for the link, but it looks like that solution is not bundling the dependencies when building the backend app, which is not what I'm looking for.  I have a little trouble wrapping my head around the fact that apps built in node can only be ran in environments that already have all of their dependencies installed.  Lots of languages have options to include dependencies at build-time, why is this not a goal in node?

Comment: Every Node environment I have used (Heroku, Elastic Beanstalk etc) install dependencies server side when you deploy your code. There is no prerequisite to install them first. Even with out such an environment you could write a hook to install on deploy without the need to bundle?

Comment: @Si-N I'm deploying to a private data center.  How do your node environments know your dependencies?  Is it inferred from your `require`/`import` statements, or do you copy over your `package.json` to your target environment?  If the latter, I don't like the idea of copying build artifacts to the runtime environment.  I've never worked on another platform before which requires that the runtime environment has knowledge of the build-time dependencies.

Comment: @David The environments I have used install from `package.json` on deployment. You can fix exact versions of the packages or use the `npm shrinkwrap` command to make sure you end up with same dependencies in production (both aren't perfect solutions though). To be honest, I'm not an expert, but I've never had any issue deploying this way and it is seems to be the recommended way for a lot of environments. However, this article agrees with your way of thinking: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-deploy-production-best-practice/

Comment: @DavidKaczynski have you found a solution for this problem? i could help with the first 2 warnings, but still struggle with the usage of ContextReplacementPlugin for express/view

Comment: @Codepunkt Thank you for your interest, and I'm sorry for the late reply.  Long story short, I did not resolve those warnings.  As I recall, I decided to ignore the warnings but resolved to revisit the issue if I was experience unexpected behavior in the app.  I mostly work on proof-of-concepts, so the application was short lived.  Out of curiosity, can you describe how you resolved the first 2 warnings in the `ws` module?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**

webpack can work with node, but it cannot extract follow require() statements.  Modifications have to be made to ignore require() in order for it to work.

**The long answer**

It is actually possible to pull some files into a master file and run it in ***some*** instances.

- One instance is if all the modules required are written in typescript and the modules are written in a away that the typescript plugin can parse the module in.
- Another instance would be if you are using es6 babel plugins and using es6 style imports.

Even in the above scenarios the blunder may choose not to pull in certain files

**The ultimate answer**

It really should not matter too much about trying to perform the long answer because modules are stored in memory at boot and then referenced later from the cache.  See the article below for more information.

http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/